# Facebook - add canvas application in install apps list

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have develop simple facebook canvas application.

http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/

I have install some other applications and they come under "apps" list on my page.

How to allow user to install my canvas application so that it will come in "apps" list.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. Facebook automatically arranges the user's **most frequently used apps** at the top of the "apps" list that you are referring to.